# How to show thumbnail of audio files from storage in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to show the audio file thumbnail with rest of information,
how can i parse the thumbnail of all the audio files

**Function for loading audio files in recycler view**

```
private void loadAudio() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        audioList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            String albumId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

            audioList.add(new AudioClass(data, title, album, artist, null));
        }

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "ContentResolver got null----------");
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

**Audio File Class for showing the files in recyclerView **

```
public class AudioClass {
String data;
String title;
String album;
String artist;
Bitmap albumArtPath;

public AudioClass(String data, String title, String album, String artist, Bitmap albumArtPath) {
    this.data = data;
    this.title = title;
    this.album = album;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.albumArtPath = albumArtPath;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getAlbum() {
    return album;
}

public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}

public Bitmap getAlbumArtPath() {
    return albumArtPath;
} }
```

The list of audio files is inflated but i cannot get the thumbnail for the audio files.

Comment: Can you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314617/get-cover-picture-by-song

Comment: this was giving me some error, but i found another answer , same way by using MediaRetriever ,, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17696852/11753476

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever).

[MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever) class provides a unified interface for retrieving frame and meta data from an input media file.

For example, the following code to get a thumbnail is an audio file.

```
public Bitmap loadThumbnail(String absolutePath) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(absolutePath);
    byte[] data = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
    retriever.release();
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
}
```

The following code is to get the name of the artist.

```
public String getArtist(String absolutePath) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(absolutePath);
    String artist = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
    retriever.release();
    return artist;
}
```